# sklearn increasing number of jobs leads to slow training

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I've been trying to get sklearn to use more cpu cores during gridsearch (doing this on a Windows machine). Code is this:

```
parameters = {'n_estimators': numpy.arange(1,10), 'max_depth':numpy.arange(1,10)}

estimator = RandomForestClassifier(verbose=1)

clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(estimator, parameters, n_jobs=-1)
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
```

I'm testing this on a small dataset of only 100 samples.

When n_jobs is set to 1 (default), everything proceeds as normal and finishes quickly. However, it only uses 1 cpu core.

In the above, I set n_jobs to -1 to use all cpu cores. When I do that (or if I use any value > 1) I can see that the correct number of cores are being utilized on my machine, but the speed is extremely extremely slow. With n_jobs = 1, the training finishes in about 10 seconds. With anything > 1, training can take 5-10minutes.

What is the correct way to increase the number of cores being used by gridsearch?

Comment: Your code seems correct to me. What is your version of `sklearn`? Can you try your code on another machine (and with different OS maybe)?

Comment: I'm using version 0.16.1. I don't have access to another machine, nor another OS unfortunately. n_jobs > 1 is problematic with basically everything else I've tried as well (beyond gridsearch)

Answer (score 1):

My suspicion is that this could be related to the fact that you're only testing it with a small dataset of 100 samples - perhaps it just isn't big enough to justify the overhead of parallelization.

It should be that for a significantly larger dataset the parallel mode will outperform the n_jobs = 1 approach.  Have you tried testing this against a much larger sample?

Comment: How large of a dataset would you say is required for the benefits to be seen?

Comment: That would depend on your data - if each entry has 1000 features the total number would be less than if you have 10 features. If you have access to a lot more entries than you could see if this solved it with some trial-and-error.