# Questions about n_jobs in sklearn.cluster.KMeans

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When I tried to execute sklearn function sklearn.cluster.KMeans(...).fit() for KMeans clustering, I found that with n_jobs = 1, it runs faster than that with n_jobs = -1. That's strange. My sklearn version is 0.23.0. 
A lot of blogs say n_jobs refers to the number of threads being called, but in Python, there may exist thread locks that disable the use of multiple threads. So I contend n_jobs stands for the use of multiprocessors.
I would appreciate it a lot if you are willing to share your own understandings.

Comment: The slowness might be from a lack of training data. Check out a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219172/sklearn-increasing-number-of-jobs-leads-to-slow-training to see if your question is answered.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. The training data in my case is kddcup 99 (correction), whose size is 494021 * 41. I think this is not a small one, compared to that similar question.

Comment: Which OS are you using? I saw that Windows is slower in such scenarios than Linux.

Comment: I am using Windows 10. My primary question is the comparison between n_jobs = 1 and n_jobs = -1 when I execute kmeans function.